# Probability that $A_n$ will happen for all large n's

Tags: probability

My task is: assess the probability that for some number $n_0$, $A_n$ will happen for every $n>n_0$, where $A_n = \{|\frac{S_n}{n} -p| \le \epsilon\}$ ($S_n $ is the number of successes in Bernoulli scheme with probability of the success equal to $p$).
I don't really understand what exactly should I do. My first attempt was that I found $P(|\frac{S_n}{n} -p| \ge \epsilon) = e^{\frac{-n\epsilon^2}{4}}$ (which was quite easy to do), but I don't know how to use it here? May somebody show me? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\gt0$ and $B_n=[|S_n/n-p|\gt x]$. What you found is probably that $P[B_n]\leqslant\mathrm e^{-xn^2/4}$ (note the sign $\leqslant$, not the sign $=$), in particular the series $\sum\limits_nP[B_n]$ converges.

By the first Borel-Cantelli lemma, the event $\limsup B_n$ has probability zero. Now, $B_n=\Omega\setminus A_n$ for every $n$ hence $\liminf A_n$ has probability one.

But, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$, the fact that $\omega$ is in $\liminf A_n$ means exactly that $|S_n(\omega)/n-p|\leqslant x$ for every $n$ large enough, that is,
$$
\omega\in\liminf A_n\iff\exists N_\omega\lt\infty,\quad\forall n\geqslant N_\omega,\quad|S_n(\omega)/n-p|\leqslant x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $E(\frac{S_n}{n})=p$, since $X_i$ are independent,$Var X_i \leq p(1-p)\leq .25 < \infty$, we can conclude $\frac{S_n}{n} \rightarrow p$ in probability, or equivalently, $\frac{S_n}{n} - p \rightarrow 0$ in probability.  That means that $P(A_n) \rightarrow 1$, since $A_n$ is the complement of $\{|\frac{S_n}{n}-p| > \epsilon\}$.

Comment: Yes, ok, I know it converges to 1, but I need to assess it, so, I guess I should have a lower bound of this probability, depending on $n_0$, am I right?